# How to add a recurring calendar event through Outlook 365 Rest Api?

Tags: php, api, calendar, office365, recurrence

I am using PHP to access the Outlook 365 REST API. I am sending following payload via POST to `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events` and receiving a 500 error in return. How is my payload misconfigured?

```
{
    "Subject":"Test Event",
    "Location": { 
        "DisplayName":"Test Location"
        },
    "Start": {
        "DateTime":"2016-09-06T00:00:00Z",
        "TimeZone":"UTC"
        },
    "End":{
        "DateTime":"2016-09-06T02:00:00Z",
        "TimeZone":"UTC"
        },
    "Body":{
        "ContentType":"HTML",
        "Content":"Stephen Colbert"
        },
    "Recurrence":{
        "Pattern":{
            "Month":0,
            "DayOfMonth":0,
            "FirstDayOfWeek":"Sunday",
            "Index":"First",
            "Type":"Daily"
            },
        "Range":{
            "NumberOfOccurrences":0,
            "Type":"EndDate",
            "EndDate":"2016-09-09",
            "StartDate":"2016-09-05",
            "RecurrenceTimeZone":"Eastern Standard Time"
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you want to create the recurrent event? If you want to create the meeting using the pattern daily, we also need use **Interval** to specify the number of units of a given recurrence type between occurrences.

Here is an example that demo to create the recurrent meeting occurring everyday from 2016-09-05 to 2016-09-09:

```
{
"Subject":"Test Event",
"Location": { 
    "DisplayName":"Test Location"
    },
"Start": {
    "DateTime":"2016-09-06T00:00:00Z",
    "TimeZone":"UTC"
    },
"End":{
    "DateTime":"2016-09-06T02:00:00Z",
    "TimeZone":"UTC"
    },
"Body":{
    "ContentType":"HTML",
    "Content":"Stephen Colbert"
    },
"Recurrence":{
    "Pattern":{
       "Interval":1,
        "Type":"Daily"
        },
    "Range":{
        "NumberOfOccurrences":5,
        "Type":"EndDate",
        "EndDate":"2016-09-09",
        "StartDate":"2016-09-05",
        "RecurrenceTimeZone":"Eastern Standard Time"
        }
    }
```

}

And you may consider to use the Outlook UI for creating recurrent event to help understanding the `RecurrencePattern` paramter. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476812/insert-recurring-event-on-office-365-api-returns-incorrect-start-and-end-date/36495983#36495983) is a similar thread for your reference.

Comment: That did the trick. Had the code put in interval only if it is greater then 1.